# Display a heading and a list created with JSX in react

Tags: reactjs

I started to learn React and i have a task to create a h1 with React.createElement and a list using JSX.I did this,but i dont understand how to display them on the website because ReactDom.render accepts only one component like i understood.
I should have this :
[image]

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const planetList = (
  <ul className='planets-list'>
    <li>Mercury</li>
    <li>Venus</li>
    <li>Earth</li>
    <li>Mars</li>
    <li>Jupiter</li>
    <li>Saturn</li>
    <li>Uranus</li>
    <li>Neptune</li>
  </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
      style: {
        color: '#999',
        fontSize: '19px'
      }
    },
    "Solar system planets"
  ),
  planetList,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I added planetList in ReactDom.render but there is an error in the console saying that:

```
react-dom.development.js:26091 Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26091:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:19:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

Can anyone give me a tip please what is wrong and how should i do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to fix your problem, but the most simplest way is to put them in an array like this:

```js
const planetList = (
  <ul className='planets-list'>
    <li>Mercury</li>
    <li>Venus</li>
    <li>Earth</li>
    <li>Mars</li>
    <li>Jupiter</li>
    <li>Saturn</li>
    <li>Uranus</li>
    <li>Neptune</li>
  </ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  [React.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
      style: {
        color: '#999',
        fontSize: '19px'
      }
    },
    "Solar system planets"
  ),
  planetList],
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Another solution could be to wrap them inside an single parent like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>{React.createElement(
"h1",
{
  style: {
    color: '#999',
    fontSize: '19px'
  }
},
"Solar system planets" )}{planetList}</div>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

instead of `div` element you can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Another solution could be create multiple component (this is common way in React) like this:

```
const PlanetList = ()=> {
  return (
   <ul className='planets-list'>
    <li>Mercury</li>
    <li>Venus</li>
    <li>Earth</li>
    <li>Mars</li>
    <li>Jupiter</li>
    <li>Saturn</li>
    <li>Uranus</li>
    <li>Neptune</li>
   </ul>
  )
}

const Header = ()=> {
  return React.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
      style: {
        color: '#999',
        fontSize: '19px'
      }
    },
    "Solar system planets"
  )
}

const App = ()=> {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header/>
      <PlanetList/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: It worked,thank you,but could you please list more  possible fixes of the problem just for documentation ? or some links to documentation because i searched but i found nothing about a similar issue

Comment: you're welcome. sure.

Comment: oh i see the second solution,i tried to do this way but it wasnt working,now i see what i have done wrong,thanks for the example,i think it's much more suitable to fix the issue,because with the array solution i got a warning in the console that i should use keys

Comment: @EvilPanda I believe that the third solution is the best one.

Comment: Yes,you are absolutely correct.I think i will practice the third one,i want to do correctly from the beggining,not to become a developer and cry in front of my code :D